# Recreate Postman settings in Angular 2

Tags: http, angular, postman

I am trying to recreate these settings from POSTMAN that allow me to authenticate to my server successfully. However in Angular 2 I don't see how can set this 'raw' setting with 'application/json' as it is needed in two places: one in Headers and one in Body.

[image]

```
//Config file
import { Headers } from 'angular2/http';
export class Config {
baseAPIUrl: string = 'http://api:8080/';
headers: Headers

constructor () {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://api:8080');
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}

// Session service
login(email: string, password: string) {
    var sessionSubscription = this.http.post(this.config.baseAPIUrl + 'auth/session', JSON.stringify({ email , password }), {
     headers: this.config.headers });
    return sessionSubscription.subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    },
    (error) => console.log('error', error));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those radio buttons are just settings for the preview of the request. Actual data is sent as JSON from client (and that's also how server receives them) which you specified with:

```
this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

To send data as plain text you should set the `Content-Type` headers like this:

```
this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

Origin headers:

```
this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://api:8080');
```

don't have effect here, you should setup `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on server side.

Comment: They are two separate files. I access all my configurations through `this.config`. It's just that when I change JSON(application/text) to anything else it gives me an error: Status 422 Unprocessable Entity

Comment: `JSON(application/text)`? Not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry I meant `JSON(application/json)`

Comment: `this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');` is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I need to recreate those settings in Postman using Angular 2, the 'raw' part specifically, if possible